# WPF Datagrid in Control in Viewbox isn't responsive

Tags: wpf, datagrid, controls, responsive, viewbox

Application with an Dashboard.
The Dashboard uses Cards in the form of User Controls. These Controls weren't responsive so I put them into Viewboxes. Some Cards are working but some don't. Especially the Cards with DataGrids in them don't work for me. Maybe you can help me out.

[DashboardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXgk7.png)

Here is the DashboardPage:

```
<Page x:Class="Keppler.MES.Common.Pages.Dashboard"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:sysglb="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Keppler.MES.Common.Pages" 
  xmlns:pageviewmodels="clr-namespace:Keppler.ViewModels.PageViewModels;assembly=Keppler.ViewModels" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Keppler.MES.Common.Pages.Controls"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  Title="DashboardPage">
<Page.DataContext>
    <pageviewmodels:VMDashboard/>
</Page.DataContext>
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..\Common\ResourceDictionaries\KepplerColorsAndBrushes.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="7*"/>

    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
      <controls:KepplerEffortCard PageName="Bookings" GroupedEfforts="{Binding EffortOfLastWorkDay}" EffortOfBindings="{Binding LastWorkDaysEffort}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
   

     <controls:KepplerEffortCard PageName="Bookings" GroupedEfforts="{Binding EffortOfLastWeek}" EffortOfBindings="{Binding LastWeeksEffort}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>

    <controls:KepplerOrdersCard PageName="Orders" Grid.ColumnSpan="12" Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="2" OrderBudgets="{Binding OrderBudgets}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}"/>
    <controls:KepplerTurnOverCard Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Header="{Binding TurnOverThisYear.Header}" TurnOver="{Binding TurnOverThisYear.TurnOver}"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0" />
    <controls:KepplerTurnOverCard Grid.Row="0" Header="{Binding TurnOverLastYear.Header}" TurnOver="{Binding TurnOverLastYear.TurnOver}"  Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="10,0" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"/>
    <controls:KepplerTurnOverCard Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Header="{Binding TurnOverThisQuarter.Header}" TurnOver="{Binding TurnOverThisQuarter.TurnOver}" Grid.Column="4" Margin="10,0"/>
    <controls:KepplerTurnOverCard Header="{Binding TurnOverThisMonth.Header}" TurnOver="{Binding TurnOverThisMonth.TurnOver}"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0"/>
    
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <controls:KepplerWarningCard PageName="Orders" WarningsInfo="{Binding BudgetWarning}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <controls:KepplerWarningCard PageName="Invoices" WarningsInfo="{Binding InvoiceWarning}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}"/>
    </Viewbox>
    
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <controls:KepplerWarningCard PageName="Orders" WarningsInfo="{Binding ResourceWarning}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}"/>
    </Viewbox>
    <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="6" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
            <controls:KepplerWarningCard PageName="Orders" WarningsInfo="{Binding DeliveryWarning}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="8" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <controls:KepplerWarningCard PageName="Orders" WarningsInfo="{Binding WorkloadWarning}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}"/>
            </Viewbox>
            <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="10" StretchDirection="Both" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                    <controls:KepplerBankingCard BankingsInfo="{Binding BankingsInfo}"/>
                </Viewbox>
    
                <controls:KepplerCustomerCard PageName="Customers" Grid.Row="7" Grid.RowSpan="2" Customers="{Binding Customers}" Grid.ColumnSpan="12" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}"/>
    <controls:KepplerProjectsCard PageName="Projects" Grid.ColumnSpan="12" Grid.Row="9" Grid.RowSpan="2" Projects="{Binding Projects}" JumpToLink="{Binding RequestPageChangeCommand}"/>


</Grid>
```

Here is the Control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Keppler.MES.Common.Pages.Controls.KepplerOrdersCard"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Keppler.MES.Common.Pages.Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="OrderBudgetCard"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="..\..\Common\ResourceDictionaries\KepplerColorsAndBrushes.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border CornerRadius="5" Margin="5" BorderThickness="0">
    <Border.BitmapEffect>
        <DropShadowBitmapEffect/>
    </Border.BitmapEffect>
    <Grid>
        <Border x:Name="DBRounded" CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF888888"/>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" CornerRadius="5,5,0,0" BorderThickness="1">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFAE00" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFC500" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
        </Border>
            <Button Background="Transparent" Command="{Binding ElementName=OrderBudgetCard, Path=JumpToLink}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=OrderBudgetCard, Path=PageName}" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border x:Name="border" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                        BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5">
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFAE00"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgOrderBudgets" 
              Background="Transparent" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=OrderBudgetCard, Path=OrderBudgets}" 
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
              VerticalGridLinesBrush="Transparent"
              BorderBrush="Transparent"
              IsReadOnly="True" Grid.RowSpan="2">

                <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="auto"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>

                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="black"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                    Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="darkred"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="order number" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Order.Number}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="budget [€]" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Order.Subtotal,StringFormat=C2, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="consumed [€]" Width="*" Binding="{Binding EffortInCash,StringFormat=C2, ConverterCulture=de-DE}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="state" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Order.Title}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>

            </DataGrid>
            <Grid.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=DBRounded}"/>
        </Grid.OpacityMask>
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

I tried putting the other Controls into Viewboxes like the Warningcards, but I didnt get anything out of it. Doesnt matter if I used fill, uniform or uniformtofill.